# CSS delivered as plaintext on github pages

Tags: html, css, github-pages

My github pages site @[americano-project.github.io](http://americano-project.github.io/) is transferring css files as plaintext, not `text/css`, causing my browser(*firefox 25.0.1*) not to load the css.

The css is embedded as so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="/css/tmp.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="/css/toast.css" />
```

The code is at [a github repo](https://github.com/americano-project/americano-project.github.io), what is causing the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `href`, not `src` (Chrome 33 also did not parse them for me until I changed the src to href).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/tmp.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/toast.css" />
```